# laravel dump(), how to dump `model->attributes`?

Tags: php, laravel, var-dump

In my views i use a lot the `@dump($model)` method, its easy to see the model's attributes like that and build forms or display data.

I want now to dump only the attributes of the model, but I get null (I assume that it is because the attributes is protected property). is there a way to do it?

```
<some html && blade>
@dump($model); // works
@dump($model->attributes); // null
// also tried: @dump($model->attributes());
```

Comment: Try `$model->getAttributes()`. `$attributes` is a protected property you can't access outside the class.

Comment: yea you don't want to dump a whole model, but you can get the attributes as ceejayoz said or you could also do   `dump($model->toArray())`, which would include attributes, loaded relationships and any appended accessors

Comment: Instead of dumping, use xdebug and breakpoint so you can see the content of an object. Also, learn how to use models, so you don't need to go dumping everything everytime, it will be better for your carreer/learning path

Comment: can use `$model->attributesToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dump model attribute you might need to do something like this

```
$user = User::find(1);

dump($user->attributesToArray());
```

This will output an array of the user's attributes and their values in the browser.

in your case it would be

```
@dump($model->attributesToArray());
```